# Problems with multiprocess-watchdog script in Python 3

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-watchdog

I have a watchdog-script to monitor a directory recursively. When an event happens I want to do something with the file.

This worked super fine, but some files are very big, so the treatment of this file blocked the watcher and some files were later missing because the watcher didn't recognize them due to the blocking.

So I thought, `multiprocessing` could help. My idea was, that the event (created, modified, ....) would start a new process and then execute the function.

I do now have a sample script that combines `watchdog` with `multiprocessing`, but I am having trouble getting it working.

```
import os
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler
from multiprocessing import Process


def print_msg(text):
    proc = os.getpid()
    print("{0} über Prozess ID: {1}".format(text, proc))

def on_created(event):
    text = "hey, {0} has been created!".format(event.src_path)
    proc = Process(target=print_msg, args=(text))
    proc.start()
    proc.join()

def on_deleted(event):
    text = "what the f**k! Someone deleted {0}!".format(event.src_path)
    proc = Process(target=print_msg, args=(text))
    proc.start()
    proc.join()

def on_modified(event):
    text = "hey buddy, {0} has been modified".format(event.src_path)
    proc = Process(target=print_msg, args=(text))
    proc.start()
    proc.join()

def on_moved(event):
    text = "ok ok ok, someone moved {0} to {1}".format(event.src_path, event.dest_path)
    proc = Process(target=print_msg, args=(text))
    proc.start()
    proc.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    patterns = "*"
    ignore_patterns = ""
    ignore_directories = False
    case_sensitive = True
    my_event_handler = PatternMatchingEventHandler(patterns, ignore_patterns, ignore_directories, case_sensitive)
    
my_event_handler.on_created = on_created
my_event_handler.on_deleted = on_deleted
my_event_handler.on_modified = on_modified
my_event_handler.on_moved = on_moved

path = "\\\swibinacl01-cifs\\BelVis\\PROD\\Importer\\Messdaten"
go_recursively = True
my_observer = Observer()
my_observer.schedule(my_event_handler, path, recursive=go_recursively)

my_observer.start()

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    my_observer.stop()
    my_observer.join()
```

When I test the script I get following message just when the first event comes up:

```
my_event_handler.on_created = on_created
NameError: name 'my_event_handler' is not defined
```

So I think that after the event (or starting the new process) the `my_event_handler` object has gone and needs to be re-initialized.

But why is that?  My thinking was, that when the event starts the function within a new process, the original process (the watcher) would continue and the new process acts independently.
What is my mistake? Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Is it normal that you call your multiprocessing functions outside the 'main' guard ? And given the sample you provided, it seems 'my_event_handler' is not defined because of 'PatternMatchingEventHandler' not returning anything, which doesn't seems to rely on multiprocessing.

Comment: My original watchdog-only script was the same as in my question but just without the multiprocessing parts in on_created, on_modified, .... That worked perfectly. So unfortunately I don't understand what you mean with "PatternMatchingEventHandler not return anything". Without the multiprocessing it returns what I expect.

Comment: Well, yes, for me it is normal how I call the multiprocessing functions, outside the 'main'. I did it that way because I want the new process to be created from the watchdog-event directly, so I put the functions in to the event-defs. I think that is the logic-mistake I made. The new processes are created at the wrong place. But how can I then execute the function by the event within a new process?

Comment: "without multiprocessing [...] that worked perfectly" you mean that 'if == main' statement does return a non empty 'my_event_handler' or you don't use 'if == main' at all ?
 "The new processes are created at the wrong place" to my knowledge you are not supposed to call your processes outside your main guard. Have you tried moving your 4 statements (on_created...) inside the if statement ?